# CodeIgniter - Variable Undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter

I put code like this in application/views/pengaduan_insert.php:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('kategori',$kategori,'', $js); ?>
```

I have tried to define $kategori in controller and model, but it always show the same error,

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: kategori

Filename: admin/pengaduan_insert.php

Line Number: 48
```

I have declared $kategori
    $kategori = $this->usermodel->ambil_kategori();

```
            //ekspand data
    foreach($kategori as $d) {
                $data['kategori'][0] = "-Pilih Kategori-";
                $data['kategori'][$d->id_kategori] = $d->kategori;
            }
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass your variable to view as well, like from function in controller, do:

```
$data["kategory"] = $kategory;
..
$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```

See:: [Reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)
Without looping the data in your controller function, just do:

```
$kategori = $this->usermodel->ambil_kategori();
$data["kategory"] = $kategory;
...
$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```

and in your view check if your variable is not empty:

```
if(!empty($kategory)) {
   echo form_dropdown('kategori',$kategori,'', $js);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the variable is `undefined`, then define it.

```
$kategori = array(
    'option 1',
    'option 2',
    'option 3',
);
```

Comment: I have defined `$kategori` in controller and model. But it always show the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do you really loop inside the `foreach` ? If not, $data['kategory'] will never exist. You should put the `$data['kategori'][0] = "-Pilih Kategori-";` before the `foreach`